# Using hook to use DISTINCT in a wp_query

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, mysql

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_product dg ON dg.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
AND ( dg.location IN ('XV', 'QV', 'DH') ) 
AND (0 OR (dg.srp = 1) OR (dg.SoldDate > (now() - interval 30 DAY) 
AND dg.isPremium = 0 AND dg.SoldDate != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND dg.SoldDate IS NOT NULL AND price > 0 AND NoImage = 0)) 
AND ( dg.deleted IS NULL OR dg.deleted <> 1 ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_product_info_new' ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY dg.SoldDate IS NULL, dg.SoldDate ASC, dg.isPremium DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

I have this query and it prevents me from doing a ORDER BY without the order changing constantly, so I thought about using DISTINCT in the wp_query? Is there a way to do this? Because it seems that we're using different hook to construct the wordpress query, and I don't know which action allows us to add a DISTINCT to the SELECT, because we have a hook for GROUP BY and a hook for ORDER BY and a hook for the joins. Also, would using DISTINCT work or will it have some unintended consequences?